# How can I get performance statistics to work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a complex query that is performing in subsecond time on my laptop, while the same query takes 70 seconds on my production server under no load against an identical schema.

The `EXPLAIN` plan is similar enough to not warrant such a massive increase in execution time, and identical in terms of the number of rows returned at each step.

This query is going against a *query only* database, so it's not a result of not having analyzed table statistics either.

I installed MySQL Workbench which seems to be a really nice tool, especially considering the fact that it's free. However, there are two sections in the explorer interface for my connection that are completely grayed out:

```
INSTANCE
  Startup/Shutdown
  Server Logs
  Options File

PERFORMANCE
  Dashboard
  Performance Reports
  Performance Schema Setup
```

I did add the following line to my `/etc/my.cnf` file and restart my server:

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema
```

And I followed the instructions in the [MySQL Performance Schema Quick Start Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html) and verified that this feature is indeed enabled.

I kicked off a job last night in order to have some statistics collected, but this morning only find:

```
Performance_schema_files_instances_lost    89804
```

while every other `performance_schema`-related variable is zero.

The error log is blank, so I have so idea how to find out how to make this work.

I am running MySQL 5.5.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL Workbench open a connection to your server and look in the managment sidebar for the **`Performance Schema Setup`**.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike. That's just it, I see the option but it is grayed out. This is Workbench 6.1.6.xxxx on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL Workbench Team blog:

Currently, only MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 are supported, because the performance_schema in MySQL 5.5 still lacked maturity and did not yet provide enough information to be very useful.

See: http://mysqlworkbench.org/2014/03/mysql-workbench-6-1-performance-schema-reports/

Answer (score 1):

Not only that you need to have MySQL server 5.6 or 5.7, but you also need the some performace_schema to be enabled and a sys schema to be installed.

On My CentOS machine I had to run:

```
mysql_upgrade   # This enabled performace_schema
service mysql restart

yum install git
git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys.git 
cd mysql-sys/ 
mysql  < ./sys_56.sql # This created sys schema and views
```

You should see over 80 views:

```
mysql -e "show full tables from sys where Table_type='VIEW'"
```

Comment: This did it for me, running the docker container. Reported it at https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/368